# Fatal error: Cannot declare class Locale, because the name is already in use in

Tags: php, configuration, migration

I have migrated my server to PHP 7.0.8 and I have the following error :

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Locale, because the name is already in use

I have a class named Locale without namespace but that works on PHP5.

How I can pass this error ?

Comment: Is this YOUR OWN class or are you using the PHP Locale class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Locale`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) class comes from the [intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). Perhaps you didn't have it installed on PHP 5?

Use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) to avoid class name conflicts. They've been in PHP for years now.